# How to get MVC button to populate and display a table after being clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've looked for 4 or 5 hours now on how to get this to work but I simply cannot figure it out.  I'm suppose to get a form that has both a submit and delete button.  The submit should submit the data in the form to a table that gets populated and created at the same time while the delete button would delete the most recent addition.  It doesn't seem to matter what I've tried to do it just doesn't work.  Whenever I click on my save button it just reloads the page with empty form fields and no table with the data.

My Controller code

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private static List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Start()
    {
        return View("PersonData");
    }

    public ActionResult AddPerson(string firstName, string lastName, string birthDate)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.firstName = firstName;
        p.lastName = lastName;
        p.birthDate = birthDate;
        if (Persons.Count > 0)
        {
            Persons.Add(p);
        }
        return View("PersonData");
    }

    public ViewResult DeletePerson()
    {
        if(Persons.Count > 0)
        {
            Persons.RemoveAt(0);
        }    
        return View("PersonData");
    }
}
```

My View code

```
@model IEnumerable<UsingViewsandModels.Models.Person>
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddPerson", "PersonController"))
{

}
<form>
    <label name="firstName">First Name: </label>        
    <input type="text" name="firstName" />
    <br />
    <label name="lastName">Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" />
    <br />
    <label name="birthDate">Birth Date: </label>
    <input type="text" name="birthDate" />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="AddPerson" onclick="AddPerson()">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" value="Delete" name="DeletePerson" onclick="DeletePerson()">Delete</button>
</form>

@if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <table>
        <tr><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th><th>BirthDate</th></tr>
        @foreach (UsingViewsandModels.Models.Person p in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>p.firstName)</td>
                <td>p.lastName)</td>
                <td>p.birthDate)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm fairly certain I'm just being an idiot and it's something very simple.

Comment: Why do you have a `Html.BeginForm()` and a `<form>` element? And the `<form>` element makes a GET back to the method that generated that view (which I assume is the `Index()` method which does not pass any data to the view. And what are your `onclick="AddPerson()` and `onclick="DeletePerson()` scripts? And `return View("PersonData");` does no make sense either.

Comment: To be honest I don't even know anymore.  the onclicks are probably just byproducts of me trying things to get it to work. The AddPerson and DeletePerson is just suppose to be action results as far as I know.  The Html.BeginForm() is also a byproduct of me trying things that I've found on the web and have not worked, so at this point I'm assuming it's not needed.  return View("PersonData") is suppose to return the updated page with both the form and table after the submit button is clicked

Comment: Not much of your code makes any sense. And is that view you have shown named `PersonData.cshtml`? And what method are you calling to display that view - the `Index()` method or the `Start()` method? And `return View("PersonData");` just returns the view - its not passing a model to it so there is no data to display.

Comment: Yes the view that is shown is PersonData.cshtml.  It's the Start() method that is calling the view I believe.  If it's just returning the view, how do I get it show the data that has been entered in the form field

Comment: `return View("PersonData", Persons);` But you will never hit the `AddPerson()` or `DeletePerson()` methods anyway as I noted in the first comment

Comment: Ok, in that case what exactly needs to be changed for those actions to be hit?

Comment: Start by replacing `<form>` with `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddPerson"))` and then you need `return View("PersonData", Persons);` (and of course a separate form and submit button for the `DeletePerson()`)

Comment: I've got those all changed now, I'm not worried as much about the 'DeletePerson()' working as I am about just being able to get the table to display and work properly with the AddPerson() action

Answer (score 0):

You have this code:

```
return View("PersonData");
```

That means: *return the view named "PersonData"*.

You are not sending no data to the view. Use the overload and send the model to your view like this:

```
return View("PersonData", Persons);
```

Now your view has access to all the data in `Persons` and it will work.

Comment: I assume you mean to change it to this return View("PersonData", Persons) After doing that, it still does not populate or display a table when hitting submit.  Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @seahawks2458 Sorry, yes that is what I mean and edited the answer. Which action did you do the change in?

Comment: I did the change in the AddPerson() action

Comment: @seahawks2458 why do you have this code: `if (Persons.Count > 0)`? I think because of that no person is ever being added to the list.

Comment: I had it there because I was just trying ways that I knew of to see if they would work.  Regardless, even after getting rid of it, it did not work